# Running Reverse Proxy on specific folder with apache2

Tags: apache-2.4

i want to run a normal website on mydomain.tld, but the directory mydomain.tld/ws should redirect / proxy to the local websocket server running on 127.0.0.1:8989.

This is what i got so far:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mydomain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.tld/

    ProxyPass /ws ws://127.0.0.1:8989/
    ProxyPassReverse /ws ws://127.0.0.1:8989/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mydomain.tld/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.mydomain.tld.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.mydomain.tld.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

However, the normal website works, but i can't connect to /ws, because i get status code 403 Forbidden, although i receive the correct http response header `X-Powered-By: Ratchet/0.3.4` which is the websocket server.

This is from the CustomLog combined:

`someip - - [15/Apr/2016:08:59:31 +0200] "GET /ws HTTP/1.1" 500 668 "-" "-"`

I'm running Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 - What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Just tried to add a subdomain, but still the same error:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ws.mydomain.tld
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPassReverse / ws://127.0.0.1:8989/
        ProxyPass / ws://127.0.0.1:8989/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to proxypass to `http://` as you listen to port 80.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ws.mydomain.tld
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8989/
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8989/
</VirtualHost>
```